# Android: Problem with 'on Click' effect

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have a problem that would be hard to explain. In my listview the list item's have imageviews. I would like to have an 'on click' or 'on pressed' effect that changes the background of the whole list row, and also the imageviews. I tried 2 approaches:

a) defining the xml selector state list for the row's layout

b) setting an onClickListener in java code

Option a) is no good because I can only change the items background and can't change the imageviews (defining a state list for imageviews is no good because it only works when the exact object is touched. and I want the effect whenever any location of the row is touched)

option b) works almost correct - i set the background resource for the layout of the list item and also change the image resource for imageviews. however, afterwards they stay like that. I am now wondering how can I change back to normal to achieve the effect of a short 'blink' in the java code. Just like with a button - you press it and it blinks orange for a split of a second.

PS: the permanent change of resources is important, because on press I open another activity with item's details and when I press the 'back button' the row looks like permanently selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with using the [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) instead of onClickListener.